# Alternative to massive if/else block for examining different exception conditions?

Tags: java, exception, if-statement

Is there a more elegant way of examining all of the possible exception types besides a massive if/else block like this?

```
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception e) {

    if (e instanceof BadException)
    {
      displayMessage("That was bad.");
    }

    else if (e instanceof ReallyBadException)
    {
      displayMessage("That was really bad.");
    }

    else if (e instanceof ReallyReallyBadException)
    {
      displayMessage("That was really really bad.");
    }

    // ...
    // and so on
    // ...

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I can see try{  throw e } catch(BadException f){}catch(ReallyBadException e){}  now is that elegant? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you control the exceptions that end up in this method, you could make use of the message embedded in them:

```
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception e) {
    displayMessage(e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

But you should only do this, if the messages are meaningful to an enduser. Normally you should handle exceptions in a way that the user doesn't notice anything is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception exception)
{
    try
    { 
        throw exception;
    }
    catch(BadException e)
    {
        displayMessage("That was bad.");
    } catch (ReallyBadException e)
    {
      displayMessage("That was really bad.");
    } catch (ReallyReallyBadException e)
    {
      displayMessage("That was really really bad.");
    }

    // ...
    // and so on
    // ...

    return null;
}
```

Comment: that's what I said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655797/alternative-to-massive-if-else-block-for-examining-different-exception-conditions/6655818#comment-7867139) but I think is quite the same thing as using `if`s

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple catch blocks, [see here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/Java%20Language/TryCatch.html).

Comment: I guess he need it inside the `resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception e)` method, so you suggest him to `throw e` and use `catch` blocks?

Comment: hmm rethrowing is not elegant. maybe he could use e.getClass() in a switch statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pre-defined Map of specific Exception type to the message you want to display:

```
private Map<Class<?>, String> exceptionMessages = ...;

public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception e) {

    if exceptionMessages.containsKey(e.getClass()) {
        displayMessage(exceptionMessages.get(e.getClass()));
    }
    else {
         // what to do by default?
    }
    return ...;
}
```

Or even better, you could externalize the Map to a properties file or ResourceBundle so you could load the user-visible string from some place other than code (and/or globalize it).

This code sample isn't capable of dealing with using the same message for a hierarchy of Exception types, but it should be pretty simple to walk the inheritance chain if the direct class is not found in the map.